# Cryptographic hash of resource fork

Tags: filesystem, file, data

In macOS, do hashing tools (shasum, crypto libs, openssl, etc), only consider the files' data forks when calculating a digest?

Does the resource fork just get ignored? If so can it be included?

Comment: Is this a question out of curiosity or are you actually using files with resource forks?

Comment: @nohillside, kinda both, looking at using codesign on apple silicon (which uses resource forks/xattr), but also for general interest.